# Can't start a session in Visual Studio Live Share

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-liveshare, live-share

I have just deinstalled and reinstalled Live Share in Visual Studio Community Edition 2022 to ensure that I have the lastest Version of this plugin installed.
When I now click on the Live-Share button in the top right corner of Visual Studio, the browser opens and says
"Visual Studio Live Share
We have retired this form of authentication. To start or join a Live Share session, please update Live Share extension to a newer version. Please see our documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/) for more details.
Please refer to the documentation for more details."

Since I just installed the lastest version of Live Share and also installed the latest update of Visual Studio Community 2022, I don't know what to do here.

"At the same time, Visual Studio says: "Please complete sign-in in the browser window , then you should be signed in automatically. If not, you may enter the user code manually." After that, I have three buttons "Cancel", "Enter user code" or "Don't show again". Hitting "Enter user code" opens a window that says: "Please complete sign-in in the browser window, then copy the user code to start the collaboration session". Since the browser doesn't allow me to sign in, I don't know what to enter here.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I had to go to Tools->Options->Live Share->Authentication and something at User Account.

Comment: In my case it was DISABLED, but when searching for the extension to install it, it was all OK... only apparently :)
thank you,  you made me get there.